# Fast access by index to array-return value

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose i have function

> array get_array($argument)

I want access to single element of this array in, so, python style like this:

> $vector = get_array($argument)[2];

There is an elegant way to do this without new variables, rewriting function and so on?

Comment: Can you explain with example what you are trying to achieve? To get array inner element, you can use `$myArray[$argument][2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use PHP 5.4, which supports  [function array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/ro/migration54.new-features.php)

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].